# Show Sum of Columns on last page only

Tags: jquery, datatables

It is very easy to follow many instructions on the web to display the sums of different columns in the footer.

**example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

My question is, How can I display the total sum only when **LAST PAGE** is opened (when the user reaches the last page in cycling)?

I was thinking of getting table info, and checking if currentpage is equal to pages before adding the code of **Total Over Pages** but I have no way to figure it out.

Has anybody tried something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by comparing `end` to the `data.length`:

```
// Update footer
if (end == data.length) {
  $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
    'Total: $' + total
  );
} else {
  $(api.column(5).footer()).html('')
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/79aLp11s/1/).

Comment: Works perfectly.. but also, if I have search filter that shows only a portion of the data, it wouldn't know that we reached the last page as `end` in this case is not equal to `data.length`. Is there a workaround for this specific situation?

Comment: Try `if (end == display.length) `